# get keys of json-object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json-object in JavaScript and I want to get the used keys in it. My JavaScript-Code looks like this:

```
var jsonData = [{"person":"me","age":"30"},{"person":"you","age":"25"}];
```

And I want a loop that alerts me 'person' and 'age', which are the keys of the first object in the json-Array.

Comment: That's a JavaScript array/object, not JSON.

Comment: yes its a duplicat. but I didn't know what I was looking for...

Answer (score 134, accepted):

[What you have is just an object, not a "json-object". [JSON](http://json.org) is a textual notation. What you've quoted is JavaScript code using an [array initializer](http://es5.github.com/#x11.1.4) and an [object initializer](http://es5.github.com/#x11.1.5) (aka, "object literal syntax").]

If you can rely on having ECMAScript5 features available, you can use the [`Object.keys`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.2.3.14) function to get an array of the keys (property names) in an object. All modern browsers have `Object.keys` (including IE9+).

```
Object.keys(jsonData).forEach(function(key) {
    var value = jsonData[key];
    // ...
});
```

---

**The rest of this answer was written in 2011. In today's world, A) You don't need to polyfill this unless you need to support IE8 or earlier (!), and B) If you did, you wouldn't do it with a one-off you wrote yourself or grabbed from an SO answer (and probably shouldn't have in 2011, either). You'd use a curated polyfill, possibly from [`es5-shim`](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim) or via a transpiler like Babel that can be configured to include polyfills (which may come from `es5-shim`).**

Here's the rest of the answer from 2011:

Note that older browsers won't have it. If not, this is one of the ones you can supply yourself:

```
if (typeof Object.keys !== "function") {
    (function() {
        var hasOwn = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;
        Object.keys = Object_keys;
        function Object_keys(obj) {
            var keys = [], name;
            for (name in obj) {
                if (hasOwn.call(obj, name)) {
                    keys.push(name);
                }
            }
            return keys;
        }
    })();
}
```

That uses a [`for..in` loop](http://es5.github.com/#x12.6.4) ([more info here](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/11/myths-and-realities-of-forin.html)) to loop through all of the property names the object has, and uses [`Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.2.4.5) to check that the property is owned directly by the object rather than being inherited.

(I could have done it without the self-executing function, but I prefer my functions to [have names](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/anonymouses-anonymous.html), and to be compatible with IE you [can't use named function expressions](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/09/double-take.html) [well, not without great care]. So the self-executing function is there to avoid having the function declaration create a global symbol.)

Answer (score 286):

```
var jsonData = [{"person":"me","age":"30"},{"person":"you","age":"25"}];

for(var i in jsonData){
    var key = i;
    var val = jsonData[i];
    for(var j in val){
        var sub_key = j;
        var sub_val = val[j];
        console.log(sub_key);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

```
var jsonObj = {"person":"me","age":"30"};
Object.keys(jsonObj);  // returns ["person", "age"]
```

`Object` has a `property` `keys`, returns an `Array` of keys from that `Object`

Chrome, FF & Safari supports `Object.keys`

Comment: This should be accepted as the correct answer. Very efficient!

Comment: is there an es6/es7 syntax to simplify this method?

Comment: I was struggling to find a method that will work with Rhino. This was it. +1

Comment: I am trying to convert rows from DB to JSON. I am getting numerical index along with actual column names as keys.  Why I am getting numerical index?

Answer (score 25):

The working code

```js
var jsonData = [{person:"me", age :"30"},{person:"you",age:"25"}];

for(var obj in jsonData){
    if(jsonData.hasOwnProperty(obj)){
    for(var prop in jsonData[obj]){
        if(jsonData[obj].hasOwnProperty(prop)){
           alert(prop + ':' + jsonData[obj][prop]);
        }
    }
}
}
```