# AngularJS DropDown with ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Let's say I have a Controller like such:

```
function MockController($scope) {
$scope.objs = [{"a": "true"},{"b": "false"}];
$scope.Value = "";
}
```

In the html view I'd have something like:

```
  <select class="input-block-level" ng-model="Value" 
  ng-options="(obj.key, obj.value) for obj in objs" required>
```

However, no matter how I try, angular doesn't seem to like the tuple notation. I tried without parenths and no dice. Is there a generic way to treat hashtables/dictionaries in ng-repeat? That is, assume you don't know the name of the key and they key itself should be used like such:

```
<option value={{obj.key}}>{{obj.value}}</option>
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't think it's possible to refer to unknown keys in `ng-options`.

I'd probably try to write a wrapper for the data somewhere along the way, converting it into something like:

```
[{"key": "a", "value": "true"},
 {"key": "b", "value": "false"}]
```

(The problem was so interesting that I actually wrote one already: http://jsfiddle.net/RCU8M/ - but that won't work in browsers without ECMAScript5 support, so you might want to fix that by using a more elegant solution, like in [get keys of json-object in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430336/get-keys-of-json-object-in-javascript) .)

Answer (score 2):

is it not

```
<select ... ng-options="(key, value) in objs" ...>
```

Comment: Let me try this. I"ll report back.

Answer (score 1):

This should be used like this:

```
<select>
<option ng-repeat="objin objs" value="{{obj.key}}">{{obj.value}}</option>
</select>
```