# Append some JSON objects to a single projection for mongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a JSON object with

> parameters.projection = {"apples" : true}
>
> parameters.projection = {"oranges" : true}
>
> parameters.projection = {"lemons" : true}

I pass `parameters` to another function that makes the call to mongoDB

I need to combine those three elements above into a single projection objection that looks like

> projection = {"apples" : true, "oranges" : true, "lemons" : true}

I have so far

> var applyParameters = function(filter){

```
var params = {};

 for(var key in filter.projection){
    //What goes here to append them?
 }    

 return params;
};
```

**No jquery** and preferably no 3rd party libraries at all. Pure JavaScript please.

Comment: Does this works ?
particularly the selected answer

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430336/get-keys-of-json-object-in-javascript

Comment: @JorgeOmarVazquez Not quite. It has to be specifically in the format above. I figured it out though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me

> var applyParameters = function(filter){

```
//Manually build the JSON object as a string
var params = "{";
var projection = filter.projection;

for(var key in projection){
    if (projection.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

        params += '"' + key + '" : ' + projection[key] + ',';
    }
}
//Make sure the projection object wasn't empty.
if(params.length > 1){
    //Strip the last comma off
    params = params.substring(0, params.length-1);
}    

params += "}";

return JSON.parse(params);
};
```