# Reading json data from remote service and printing specific elements

Tags: javascript, json

Hi I have this json object data from service

```
{
    "Result": [
        {
            "Status": {
                "StatusCode": 200,
                "Text": "Successful"
            }
        },
        {
            "ListByPI": {
                "ORCA_ID": "25746",
                "ProtocolID": "20140476HU",
                "PIName": "DeFronzo"
            }
        },
        {
            "ListByPI": {
                "ORCA_ID": "21273",
                "ProtocolID": "20120202HU",
                "PIName": "DeFronzo"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I get the values of `ORCA_ID`, `ProtocolID` and `PIName`?

Comment: where you want to read means javascript, php or java

Comment: That's a JSON object, you need to 'deserialize' it. 
What language are you using for your application?

Comment: Where you do want to parse this json?? In PHP or js or android?

Comment: What do you want? You ask for a javascript solution and accept one with Java, then you ask more things in comments... You should read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can for example use a `for` and loop through your desired element, as seen in [get keys of json-object in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8430501/1983854):

```
for (k in s.Result[1].ListByPI) {
    document.write(k);   
}
```

See it in action:

```js
var s = {
    "Result": [
        {
            "Status": {
                "StatusCode": 200,
                "Text": "Successful"
            }
        },
        {
            "ListByPI": {
                "ORCA_ID": "25746",
                "ProtocolID": "20140476HU",
                "PIName": "DeFronzo"
            }
        },
        {
            "ListByPI": {
                "ORCA_ID": "21273",
                "ProtocolID": "20120202HU",
                "PIName": "DeFronzo"
            }
        }
    ]
};

for (k in s.Result[1].ListByPI) {
    document.write(k);   
}
```

Also in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xvsgL6cx/).

---

#### Update

If you don't want to specify `Result[` + number + `]`, then you can loop through them like this:

```
for (i in s.Result) {
   document.write('we are in id);
   for (k in s.Result[i].ListByPI) {
       document.write(k);   
   }
}
```

See it in action:

```js
var s = {
    "Result": [
        {
            "Status": {
                "StatusCode": 200,
                "Text": "Successful"
            }
        },
        {
            "ListByPI": {
                "ORCA_ID": "25746",
                "ProtocolID": "20140476HU",
                "PIName": "DeFronzo"
            }
        },
        {
            "ListByPI": {
                "ORCA_ID": "21273",
                "ProtocolID": "20120202HU",
                "PIName": "DeFronzo"
            }
        }
    ]
};

for (i in s.Result) {
   document.write('we are in id);
   for (k in s.Result[i].ListByPI) {
       document.write(k);   
   }
}
```

Comment: how to get all values of ORCA_ID,ProtocolID,PIName

Comment: what do you mean? Update your question indication what is *exactly* your desired output.

Comment: you code will display keys  ORCA_ID,ProtocolID,PIName valuea but I want the values 25746,20140476HU,DeFronzo not the keys.

Comment: @RajaSekharReddyBolle then you can say: `alert(k + " = " + s.Result[1].ListByPI[k]);`. Check it and indicate if it works to you.

Comment: the above will work but everytime we have to pass Result[1 0r 2 or 3] values,how to get all data by passing dynamically values to Result{] array

Comment: @RajaSekharReddyBolle I did some changes in my answer, check them out.

Comment: In the above code If I  don't know object types like Result,Status and ListByPI then how can I get the data?

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you can use json_decode and extract like this

```
<?php
$contents = '{
"Result":[
{
"Status":{
"StatusCode":200,
"Text":"Successful"
}
},
{
"ListByPI":{
"ORCA_ID":"25746",
"ProtocolID":"20140476HU",
"PIName":"DeFronzo"
}
},
{
"ListByPI":{
"ORCA_ID":"21273",
"ProtocolID":"20120202HU",
"PIName":"DeFronzo"
}
}
]
}';

$json = json_decode($contents, true); 



echo "In Result  first ORCA_ID is ".$json['Result'][1]['ListByPI']['ORCA_ID']."<br>"; //Here result is an array...So Indexs should be mentioned... then string name

      ?>
```

And output is

```
In Result, first ORCA_ID is 25746
```

Comment: I want to get in javascript

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse it by using java, then you can use the following:

```
String json = "{\"Result\":[{\"Status\":{\"StatusCode\":200,\"Text\":\"Successful\"}},{\"ListByPI\":{\"ORCA_ID\":\"25746\",\"ProtocolID\":\"20140476HU\",\"PIName\":\"DeFronzo\"}},{\"ListByPI\":{\"ORCA_ID\":\"21273\",\"ProtocolID\":\"20120202HU\",\"PIName\":\"DeFronzo\"}}]}";

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);

JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Result");

for (int i = 1; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("ListByPI");
    System.out.println("ORCA_ID = " + object.getString("ORCA_ID") + " --- ProtocolID = " + object.getString("ProtocolID"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can write this:

 var temp = {"Result": [
               { "Status": { "StatusCode": 200, "Text": "Successful" } },
               { "ListByPI": { "ORCA_ID": "25746", "ProtocolID": "20140476HU", "PIName": "DeFronzo" } },
               { "ListByPI": { "ORCA_ID": "21273", "ProtocolID": "20120202HU", "PIName": "DeFronzo" } }]
                };
                temp["Result"][0].Status.StatusCode;
                temp["Result"][0].Status.Text;
                temp["Result"][1].ListByPI.ORCA_ID;
                temp["Result"][1].ListByPI.ProtocolID;
                temp["Result"][1].ListByPI.PIName;
                temp["Result"][2].ListByPI.ORCA_ID;
                temp["Result"][2].ListByPI.ProtocolID;
                temp["Result"][2].ListByPI.PIName;
            }
```

Comment: If the "ListByPI"  repetition is not known then how we will get the values instead of passing 1 and 2 values to temp["Result"][1 or 2].ListByPI.ORCA_ID;