# How to read key-value pairs from a list of hashmaps which is in the form of json in jquery script?

Tags: java, jquery, json

Context : `Json`,`Jquery`,`Java`

The json object like this :

```
[{"7818.0":".NET Developer"},{"6124.0":".Net Off Shore Support Project Manager"},{"6125.0":".Net Off Shore Support Project Member"},{"6922.0":"2 APAC Inventory Orgs Under SPSW Manager"}]
```

The code in Jquery :

```
var roles = <%=request.getAttribute("roleList")%>
$.each(roles, function(object) {
                //display the key and value pair
                alert(object.key);
                alert(object.value);
            });
```

Any suggestions is really appreciated

Comment: Here json object does not have the structure with name variable. You can use index alert(object[0]);

Comment: Your life would be much easier if your JSON objects had the form `{"code":"7818.0", "name":".NET Developer"}`

Comment: possible duplicate of [get keys of json-object in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430336/get-keys-of-json-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code to :

```
$.each(roles, function(key,value) {
   for (var i in value) {
      alert("Key: "+i);
      alert("Value: "+value[i]);
   }                 
});
```

get the key and value from the map.

Here's the working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/pr21ojof/