# how to get left side data of a json dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json which is like

```
{
"Payload":[{
    "PrevYr":"21333",
    "CurYr":"123454"
},{
    "PrevYr":"234333",
    "CurYr":"45546"
},{
    "PrevYr":"3563",
    "CurYr":"67854"
}]
}
```

Now in my code i read this json using

```
  $.getJSON("readJson.json", function (data) {}
```

I need to read the json and create another json with some changes on it. But i can't read the "CurYr" and "PrevYr". I mean not their values. But them. So if there is 2014 and 2015 in place of curyr and prevyr i can get them also. I need to read the left side. Please help..

Comment: Object.keys(objectName)

Comment: this might be help..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430336/get-keys-of-json-object-in-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting JavaScript object key list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068534/getting-javascript-object-key-list)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this,

```
    var test = {
"Payload":[{
    "PrevYr":"21333",
    "CurYr":"123454"
},{
    "PrevYr":"234333",
    "CurYr":"45546"
},{
    "PrevYr":"3563",
    "CurYr":"67854"
}]};

$.each(test.Payload,function(key,val){
        $.each(val,function(key1,val1){
        alert(key1);
    }); 
});
```

or

```
var keySet = Object.keys( test.Payload[0] );
 alert( keySet[0]);
 alert( keySet[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Object.keys( obj );](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

try

```
$.getJSON("readJson.json", function (data) {

 console.log( Object.keys(data.Payload[0]));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
var obj = {
"Payload":[{
    "PrevYr":"21333",
    "CurYr":"123454"
},{
    "PrevYr":"234333",
    "CurYr":"45546"
},{
    "PrevYr":"3563",
    "CurYr":"67854"
}]
}

var objKeys = Object.keys(obj);

objKeys.forEach(function(key){
  // This returns "Payload"
  var _innerKeys = Object.keys(obj[key]);
  
  // This returns "0,1,2" since obj[key] is an array.
  _innerKeys.forEach(function(k){
    
    // This will return "PrevYr, CurYr"
    var _innerProp = Object.keys(obj[key][k]);
    console.log(_innerProp);
  })
  console.log("Inner Keys: ", _innerKeys);
})
```