# How can I get the id from a JSON object

Tags: json, angular, angular7

How can I get the id of an object?

In this example I want to get the 'ok' and store it in a variable.
I know how to access the data.I need to access the id and store it for some purpose.

I use Angular so the console log is like this
'console.log (this.Data');'

{ok: Array(2)}
ok: Array(2)
.
.
.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i find the solution.I changed the object.I set an 'id' and a 'data' field.Now i can access it like this.Data.id and this.Data.data.

Answer (score 0):

Always depends in your JSON structure but if you want the object inside the 'ok' key you can access through the key, for example:

```
{
  "ok": Array(2) 
}
```

You can access with the key associated at the object:

```
this.Data.ok;
this.Data[ok];
```

Comment: I mean i need to get only the id (i know how to get the data) i just want to get the array id which is 'ok' in this case.

Comment: Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430336/get-keys-of-json-object-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can get every key from your JSON with Object.keys.
`Object.keys(this.data)`